# Keep Activities in stack, but return only to the main

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have nine activities. For example, Activity "A" is the main. The user opens from the NavigationDrawer the Activity "B", "С", "D" and in "D" he clicks on the "back" button. In this case, need to return to Activity "A" and not pass through the entire stack of recently opened activities.

This code does what I need:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.A:
                if (item.isChecked()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            intent = new Intent(activity, A.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, 250);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.B:
                if (item.isChecked()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (activity instanceof A) {
                        userFlavorsMap.clear();
                        if (flavorContainer.getChildCount() > 0){
                            flavorContainer.removeAllViews();
                        }
                    }
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            intent = new Intent(activity, B.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, 250);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.C:
                if (item.isChecked()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (activity instanceof A) {
                        userFlavorsMap.clear();
                        if (flavorContainer.getChildCount() > 0){
                            flavorContainer.removeAllViews();
                        }
                    }
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            intent = new Intent(activity, C.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, 250);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.D:
                if (item.isChecked()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (activity instanceof A) {
                        userFlavorsMap.clear();
                        if (flavorContainer.getChildCount() > 0){
                            flavorContainer.removeAllViews();
                        }
                    }
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            intent = new Intent(activity, D.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, 250);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.E:
                if (item.isChecked()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (activity instanceof A) {
                        userFlavorsMap.clear();
                        if (flavorContainer.getChildCount() > 0){
                            flavorContainer.removeAllViews();
                        }
                    }
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            intent = new Intent(activity, E.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, 250);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.F:
                File usersCounter = new File("data/data/com.com.com/shared_prefs/file.xml");
                if (usersCounter.exists()) {
                    if (item.isChecked()) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        if (activity instanceof A) {
                            userFlavorsMap.clear();
                            if (flavorContainer.getChildCount() > 0){
                                flavorContainer.removeAllViews();
                            }
                        }
                        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                intent = new Intent(activity, F.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                activity.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }, 250);
                    }
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (item.isChecked()) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        if (activity instanceof A) {
                            userFlavorsMap.clear();
                            if (flavorContainer.getChildCount() > 0){
                                flavorContainer.removeAllViews();
                            }
                        }
                        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                intent = new Intent(activity, G.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                activity.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }, 250);
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But, if user switched to Activity, for example, "C" and folded the application, then after return to app will open "A". How can I complete the code so that when I return to the application, it open the last opened Activity, but all the recent activities are not going to be in the stack?

In manifect *android:launchMode="singleTop"*

Comment: override onBackPressed method and start main activity there

Comment: If you dont want to be able to go back to certain activities, `finish()` them as you open the next one. So when you press back, they aren't in the stack, just A.

Answer (score 0):

try this in each activity except MainActivity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivityName.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: If you are going down this route, you need the right flags. Else pressing back from A will take you back to the activity before the one you just closed. e.g. B or C

Comment: But in this case I'm I will lose the information entered in the MainActivity. Is there a solution with flags or launchModes?